# Injecting trusted JavaScript into (Chrome) WebExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a WebExtension for Chrome. The purpose of this extension is to analyze all URLs before they are called. URLs are passed as parameter to a JavaScript function `checkUrl`. The analysis is performed inside this function.

The problem is that the JavaScript function is in a file, which is changed frequently. Therefore, it is no option to include this file into the extension. The file is supplied from a trusted source.

The current state is as followed:

background.js

```
// get file's content
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage( "myNativeApp", { text : "getMyFunc" },
function( response )
{
    var contentFromFile = response.text;
});

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener( ( details ) => {
    var calledUrl = details.url;

    if ( checkUrl( calledUrl ) === true )
    {
        [...]
    }
});
```

file.js (in local filesystem and not part of extension)

```
function checkUrl( url )
{
    [...]
}
```

At browser start the file's content is read out and sended to the extension via native messaging.

Is it possible to execute the function `checkUrl` which is stored in `contentFromFile`? I guess that this is not possible, because code is injected into the extension.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A secure method is to create a [sandboxed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox) iframe inside the background page where you can `eval()` your external code and use DOM messaging via [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate with the background page script. Alternatively you can relax the default CSP which is a terrible idea though.